# Easiest way to get \not\longrightarrow to look good

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I'm currently using `\longrightarrow` to mean "tends to [some limit]", and sometimes I need to use its negation. I see that there is an `\nrightarrow`, but unfortunately it doesn't make a matching pair with `\longrightarrow`, and `\not\longrightarrow` looks quite bad. What's the easiest way to adjust the position of the little slash so that I can define a `\nlongrightarrow`? The solution from this [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13938/how-do-i-create-the-negated-arrow-on-xrightarrow) looks excellent but seems to be overkill for my purposes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally, you can often achieve better results by using the `\centernot` macro from the [`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) package instead of the normal `\not` command.

In this case, however, the [`stmaryrd`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) package offers the special `\longarrownot`/`\Longarrownot` macros you can use for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
    $\centernot\longrightarrow$ % with centernot
    $\longarrownot\longrightarrow$ % with stmaryrd
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

`centernot`: [image: result with centernot], `stmaryrd`: [image: result with stmaryd]

Answer (score 3):

If you need the symbol only in text size, you can say

```
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\newcommand\nlongrightarrow{
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$\longrightarrow$\cr
    \hskip 0pt plus .5fill $\arrownot$\hskip 0pt plus 2fill\cr}}
}
```

The skip values were found by trial and error. I would use `\rightarrow` and `\nrightarrow` anyway; personal taste, I'd say. :)