# Moving a subscript in Xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic

To obtain a larger version of `\nrightarrow` (LaTeX, Package amssymb), I typed

```
$\xymatrix{A\ar@<-1.5ex>@{}[r]^{/}\ar[r]&B}$
```

Is there a simpler way to obtain the same result, i.e. is it possible to move upward or downward the subscript (or the superscript) of an arrow?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's almost always to post a full example instead of only a fragment of code

Comment: How do you want to use this arrow? In a formula or like in your example or in text? Would a bigger scaled `\nrightarrow` work for you?

Comment: The fragment of code was just an example. The question is: "Is it possible to move upward or downward the subscript (or the superscript) of an arrow?" (assuming the arrow is horizontal...)".

Comment: I see no subscript or superscript.

Comment: The aim is to draw an arrow, and in the middle of it a slash, without breaking the arrow. The solution above is made of three steps:

Comment: 1. draw an invisible arrow shifted downwards (code \ar@<-1.5ex>@{}[r]) 2. Draw a superscript, here, a slash (code ^{/}) 3. draw another arrow (code \ar[r]).

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13940, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16173, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201659, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51022. In general: take a look to [tag:tikz-cd] which is easier and more powerful than [tag:xy-pic]. Or you scale and position your `\nrightarrow` to your needs. It is still very unclear, what subscript and superscript you are talking about. Please spend some more time in asking a clear question with an MWE! Thanks.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47063

Comment: Is your problem solved with my answer? If yes, please consider to [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it in order to close this post. If not, please tell us, what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Really easy negation can be done with `centernot`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}
$\rightarrow\centernot\rightarrow\longrightarrow\centernot\longrightarrow\Rightarrow\centernot\Rightarrow\Longrightarrow\centernot\Longrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could negate anything with that. If you want to use a commutative diagram approach, take a look on [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd). If you want to have the `amssymb` arrow, you will have to scale this up or do a feature request to the maintainers.