# How do I create a negated arrow on \xRightarrow?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13938/how-do-i-create-the-negated-arrow-on-xrightarrow), but with the `\xRightarrow` instead. I tried changing the 3rd version to use `\Rightarrow` like so:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \diagup
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz} % for tikz solution

\makeatletter
\def\slashedarrowfill@#1#2#3#4#5{%
  $\m@th\thickmuskip0mu\medmuskip\thickmuskip\thinmuskip\thickmuskip
   \relax#5#1\mkern-7mu%
   \cleaders\hbox{$#5\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
   \mathclap{#3}\mathclap{#2}%
   \cleaders\hbox{$#5\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
   \mkern-7mu#4$%
}

\def\rightslashedarrowfillc@{%
  \slashedarrowfill@\relbar\relbar{\raisebox{.12em}{\tiny/}}\Rightarrow}
\newcommand\xslashedrightarrowc[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\rightslashedarrowfillc@}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    A \xslashedrightarrowc{abcdefg} C\\[12pt]
\end{document}
```

But I end up with this instead:

[image: slashed arrows again]

I'm assuming something's wrong with the def of `\slashedarrowfill` but I don't know enough to fix it. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heiko Oberdiek's `centernot` package comes in handy for that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$\centernot{\xRightarrow{sdfkjhsdf}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following test file adds new macros `\x(n)(Left|Right|Leftright)arrow` similar to the definitions of package `amsmath`. The negated arrows use help macro `\narrowfill@` with the symbol `\neq` in the middle of the stretchable area of the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\xRightarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0359\Rightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\xLeftarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 3095\Leftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\xLeftrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 3399\Leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\xnRightarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0359\nRightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\xnLeftarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 3095\nLeftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\xnLeftrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 3399\nLeftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\nRightarrowfill@}{%
  \narrowfill@\Relbar\Relbar\Rightarrow\neq
}
\newcommand*{\nLeftarrowfill@}{%
  \narrowfill@\Leftarrow\Relbar\Relbar\neq
}
\newcommand*{\nLeftrightarrowfill@}{%
  \narrowfill@\Leftarrow\Relbar\Rightarrow\neq
}

\newcommand*{\narrowfill@}[5]{%
  $\m@th\thickmuskip0mu\medmuskip\thickmuskip\thinmuskip\thickmuskip
  \relax#5#1\mkern-7mu%
  \cleaders\hbox{$#5\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-5mu %
  #4%
  \mkern-5mu %
  \cleaders\hbox{$#5\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu#3$%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A &\xRightarrow[below]{above} B      & C &\xRightarrow{} D \\
  A &\xnRightarrow[below]{above} B     & C &\xnRightarrow{} D \\
  A &\xLeftarrow[below]{above} B       & C &\xLeftarrow{} D \\
  A &\xnLeftarrow[below]{above} B      & C &\xnLeftarrow{} D \\
  A &\xLeftrightarrow[below]{above} B  & C &\xLeftrightarrow{} D \\
  A &\xnLeftrightarrow[below]{above} B & C &\xnLeftrightarrow{} D
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The height and depth of `\neq` is automatically taken into account and the superscript and subscript are moved to avoid clashes with the slash.
- If package `mathtools` is needed, load it afterwards. It also defines `\xLeftarrow`, `\xRightarrow`, and `\xLeftrightarrow`, but IMHO the spacing of the versions of `mathtools` is too tight with possible visual clashes of the annotations with the arrow head.

Answer (score 3):

The previous is solution somewhat buggy because you have to manually set the `\kern length`.
I would prefer to define a simple macro `\NOT` as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\NOTskip} 
\def\NOT#1{\settowidth{\NOTskip}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
            \hspace{0.5\NOTskip}\mathclap{\not}\hspace{-0.5\NOTskip}#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
 A \NOT{\xRightarrow{bla}} C \NOT{\xleftarrow[\text{et caetera}]{}} Z
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

producing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
I'ld try something like this:

```
\kern.8em\not\kern -.8em \xRightarrow[ablalba]{}
```

Here in an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[ \kern.8em\not\kern -.8em \xRightarrow[Text goes here]{and here} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi oerpli: to make your answer more useful to future visitors, you could (1) mention that you need the `mathtools` package (or better yet: turn your code snippet into a complete, small `.tex` file), and (2) include an image showing the output.

Comment: i've added a .tex file - image is not possible from my end at the moment.

Comment: Your code as it is now, won't compile. Besides, it has unnecessary packages. You can reduce your code to `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\kern.8em\not\kern -.8em \xRightarrow[ablalba]{}
\]

\end{document}`.